# Illegal instruction (core dumped) CGAL4.13 istringstream to EK::FT

Tags: c++, gcc, cgal

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel EK;

int main() {

  std::istringstream s;
  s.str("0.01\t3E-5\t4E-4\n");
  std::cout<< s.str();
  for (int n=0; n<3; n++) {
    EK::FT val;
    s >> val;
    std::cout << val << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I was trying to read in a string into three EK::FT variables. The code compiled but I got Illegal instruction (core dumped) error while executing the line "s>>val". This code worked in previous environment. And if I change the variable of val to double, it worked. Currently I use gcc (GCC) 9.3.0 compiler on Rocky 8 OS.

Comment: Could you tell what version of CGAL you are using, and turn your code into a [mcve] (with `#include`, etc) so we can more easily reproduce it?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I have turned it into a reproducible example. I am using CGAL 4.13

Comment: Even with gcc-9 and CGAL-4.13 I am not seeing it. How are you compiling exactly? Did you copy some binaries (like libgmp) over from another machine? Could you compile with -g, execute in gdb, then print the instruction that was illegal?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I think that is probably the case. I reinstalled the other libraries and that error is gone. Thanks for your help.